# SharePoint Timer Job time is -2 hours from server time

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

I have a couple of custom timer jobs that I have installed on my SP Foundation server. The server is running in Virtual Box, Server 08R2, it has been added to my domain and the time on the server appears in sync with the time on my local machine. The problem I have is that the time that the timer jobs say they are running is 2 hours behind what my server, local machine, domain say the time is. This is causing me some grief in my testing. I am not sure how it got into this state and I can't seem to find a way to get it back to the timer jobs being in synch with the server they are running on. Any ideas?

Edit:
Additional information. I added a logging statement into the timer job to output the result of DateTime.Now to the sharepoint log. The result of that call is the same as the server time, even though still in the central admin control the timer jobs appear as if they are running 2 hours behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check time zones
- Check day light savings
- Check the locale's of all the site collections

Comment: What do you mean by locales?